Can foreign hours (solo/sim) be counted?
I am starting flight training overseas first (with sim and some in-aircraft hours) and was wondering should the instructor(local governing body approved instructor but not FAA certified), sign off my solo and I accumulate solo time overseas (+ XC), can these hours flown be counted towards solo (and solo XC) requirements towards PPL and ultimately IFR (the 50 hrs PIC requirement).
And to add on, can an overseas FAA approved FTD used by me and said instructor be counted towards sim time for ppl/IR rating?
since The rules on logging as per 14 CFR 61.51.
Logging training time in a simulator is allowed by 61.51(h):
(h) Logging training time. (1) A person may log training time when that person receives training from an authorized instructor in an aircraft, full flight simulator, flight training device, or aviation training device.
and
a maximum of 2.5 hours of training in a full flight simulator or flight training device representing the category, class, and type, if applicable, of aircraft appropriate to the rating sought, may be credited toward the flight training time required by this section, if received from an authorized instructor.
Must the authorized instructor, in this case, be a FAA certified CFI or does a local one count?
